# How to disable Google translating the search query language?

Tags: google-search, localization

My primary language is English and all the settings are set accordingly but I am fluent in a number of languages and use to search for things in them too.

When I write a search query in a particular language I want to see occurrences of what I have written, not of its other languages translations. For example when I search for "hybrid" (in English) I want to see the pages containing "hybrid", "hybrids", etc. When I search for "гибрид" (the same word in Russian) I want to see the pages containing "гибрид", "гибриды", "гибрида" etc. but NOT  "hybrid", "hybrids", etc. but in reality if I look for "гибрид" (a Russian word) I get results for both "гибрид" and "hybrid" mixed together with the English version dominating. How do I get rid of this?

In both cases it doesn't matter in what of the languages the text ow the results will be? for example if I look for an English word I don't mind a text in Russian containing just this particular word in English.

The things used to work the way I prefer them to in the past but Google tries to be more "smart" today, which I find annoying.

UPDATE: Another good example of how this feature screws up the things is that searching for "ПСС" ("Полное Собрание Сочинений" - "complete set of works" (of a particular author (writer))) gives me results for "GCC" ("Gnu Compilers Collection") instead.

Comment: Yes, @pnuts, I always use ncr. http://google.com/ncr is my home page.

Comment: Even quotes don't work by the way. It is nasty to know no way to search for exact occurrences.

Comment: No, @pnuts, "narrow your results by language" limits results by the page language while I still want all the languages. All I want is to find all the web pages (regardless to what is the major language of them) at which the particular piece of text occurs.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways you can do this:

1. Use [Google Advanced Search](http://www.google.com/advanced_search) to specify the language.
2. Add a language parameter to your search query. For Russian, the parameter is `&lr=lang_ru`.

Comment: This is only a partial workaround and does not solve the problem. For example this would not find English pages that have the Russian word "гибрид", and it *will* find Russian pages with the English word "hybrid".